# Adding/Deleting an object to an Obervable of an object array in Angular/RXJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

**Goal:** To add an object to an existing Observable array of objects. Having this reflect on the DOM is the final step.

`NewObject.ts`:

```
export class NewObject {
  name: string;
  title: string;
}
```

Here's the `example.component.ts`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NewObject } from 'objects';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  // Initializing the object array Observable from a service (step 1)
  readonly objects$: Observable<NewObject[]> = this.objectSvc.getAllObjects("objects").pipe(
    map(obj => obj.map(x => ({ name: x.name, title: alterString(x.title) }))),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  constructor(
    private objectSvc: ObjectService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    somethingThatHappensToAdd = (response: any) => {
      let data = JSON.parse(response);
      data.forEach(x => {
        let obj: NewObject = { name: x.name, title: alterString(x.title) }

        // Here's where I'm trying to add the obj object into the already existing object array Observable
      });
    };

    somethingThatHappensToDelete = (response: any) => {
      let data = JSON.parse(response);
      data.forEach(x => {
        let obj: NewObject = { name: x.name, title: alterString(x.title) }

        // Here's where I'm trying to delete the obj object from the already existing object array Observable
      });
    };

  }
}
```

This is my `example.component.html`:

```
<div *ngFor="let o of objects$ | async">
   <p>{{ o.name }}</p>
   <p>{{ o.title}}</p>
</div>
```

Here's my service `object.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ClientApi, ApiException, NewObject } from '../client-api.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ObjectService {

  constructor(
    private clientApi: ClientApi
  ) { }

  getAllObjects(name: string): Observable<NewObject[]> {
    return this.clientApi.getAllObjects(name)
      .pipe(
        map((x) => x.result),
        catchError(err => {
          if (ApiException.isApiException(err)) {
            if (err.status === 404) {
              return of<NewObject[]>(undefined);
            }
          }
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

After formatting of the response in `JSON`, I want to be able to insert the `obj` object into `objects$` Observable and have it reflect on the UI.

I am advised to use a `BehaviorSubject` element to make this happen. Can anyone advise on how this can be easily done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two ways to go about this solution.

**Solution 1:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rajvqq

```
constructor(private myService: MyService){
  this.myService.getObjects().subscribe(x => this.somethingThatHappensToAdd(x));
}

resultsArray = []
resultsSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.resultsArray);

readonly objects$: Observable<number[]> = combineLatest(
  this.resultsSubject,
).pipe(
  map(([results]) => ([...results])),
  shareReplay(1)
)

somethingThatHappensToAdd( arrayOfValues ) {
  arrayOfValues.forEach(x => {
    this.resultsArray.push(x)          
  });
  this.resultsSubject.next(this.resultsArray)
};

delete(o: any) {

  // This is the same as just accessing this.resultsArray
  let newArray: any[] = this.resultsSubject.getValue();
  for (let i = newArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (newArray[i] == o) {
      newArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  this.resultsSubject.next(newArray);
}
```

**Solution 2:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxfk16

```
deleteSubject = new Subject<any>();
addSubject = new Subject<any[]>();

objects$ = this.myService.getObjects().pipe(
  switchMap(x => merge(
    of(x), 
    this.deleteSubject.pipe(map(y => this.deleteAll(y, x))),
    this.addSubject.pipe(map(y => { x.push(...y); return x; }))
  )),
  shareReplay(1)
);
constructor(private myService: MyService){ }

deleteAll(o: any, v: any[]) {
  for (let i = v.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (v[i] == o) {
      v.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `BehaviorSubject` to emit results coming from `somethingThatHappens()` and  use `combineLatest()` to merge the results with the ones coming from the service.

```
objectsFromService$ = this.objectSvc.getAllObjects("objects").pipe(
    map(obj => obj.map(x => ({ name: x.name, title: alterString(x.title) })))
);

resultsArray = []
resultsSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this.resultsArray);
results$ = this.resultsSubject.asObservable()

readonly objects$: Observable<NewObject[]> = combineLatest(
    this.results$,
    this.objectsFromService$
).pipe(
   map(([results, objects]) => ([...results, ...objects])),
   shareReplay(1)
)


somethingThatHappens = (response: any) => {
      let data = JSON.parse(response);
      data.forEach(x => {
        let obj: NewObject = { name: x.name, title: alterString(x.title) }
        this.resultsArray.push(obj)          
      });
      this.resultsSubject.next(this.resultsArray)
};
```

I created a working stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnngwh

Hope this gives you a clue.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution when it comes to adding additional items to the array. Will this cause problems if you were to delete items?

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) this should not cause any problems

Comment: Looks like there's a bit of a problem with regards to deleting, can you offer any help, I've replicated the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-22trl1

Comment: Of course. I will have a look at once I get to my pc tomorrow

Comment: I had a look at the code you shared. The problem is that you are trying to remove the items came from the service. In order to remove them, you need to remove it from the source which is the `Observable` of the service, since you want to use `async` pipe.

Comment: Would it be possible to see what you mean via code example? Would it help if I were to draft another question, or not necessary?

Comment: No it's not necessary to post another question. You could share the methods of your service (to see if it fetches the data from an API) by editing the question so that I can provide more help

Comment: I just now shared. Question revised :). Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Looks like I got this working - similar deviation to yours: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5lflg - if you revise your answer to anything similar to this, I'll accept!

Answer (score 0):

I think Harun answer is good (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60108390/1974681)

If you are only updating this observable once (on init) you could do something as simple as:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

    let objects$: Observable<NewObject[]>;

    constructor(
        private objectSvc: ObjectService
    ) { }

    private initializeObservable() {
        return this.objectSvc.getAllObjects("objects").pipe(
            map(obj => obj.map(x => ({ name: x.name, title: alterString(x.title) }))),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
    }

    private getObservableWithNewValues() {
        const response = callService();
        let array = [];
        let data = JSON.parse(response);
        data.forEach(x => {
            let obj: NewObject = { name: x.name, title: alterString(x.title) }
            array.push(obj);
        });

        // This creates an observable of the array
        return of(array);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        const initialObservable = this.initializeObservable();

        const anotherObservable = this.getObservableWithNewValues();

        this.objects$ = concat(initialObservable, anotherObservable);
    }
}
```

Refs:

- https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of
- https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat